Is any solution for remix dynamic route name divided by "-"?
I need implement route with name: /someroute-1, /someroute-2 ... and so on.
With dynamic part after "-"
For example: app/routes/someroute-$id
p.s: NOT app/routes/someroute/$id
I tried app/routes/someroute-$id, it is doesn't work

Does this answer your question? How to add partial dynamic segments in the react router v6?

No. In React Router 6 (and Remix), dynamic params must be the entire URL segment (the part between the /).
You have to do something like app/routes/$someroute, and in your loader, parse params.someroute to extract the id.
